# Extract href in table with importxml in Google spreadsheet

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to pull the href for each row of each table from this website:

```
http://www.epa.gov/region4/superfund/sites/sites.html#KY
```

I can pull the table information off using `=IMPORTHTML(A1,"table",1)` for all 7 tables, but I need the `href` to the site with the detailed information.

Using `=IMPORTxml(A1,"//div[@class='box']")` I can pull the information needed from a site like:

```
http://www.epa.gov/region4/superfund/sites/fedfacs/alarmyaplal.html
```

but I need to extract the `fedfacs/alarmyaplal.html` portion for each row on the original page.

I've tried using `//@href`, but it is not returning any results.  I'm thinking it is because the data is structured in a table but I'm stuck on where to go from here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about any of the Google Spreadsheet functionality, but here's an XPath to select all `href` attributes of the Kentucky sites (since your first link included the 'ky' anchor):

```xml
//body//a[@id='ky']/following-sibling::table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/strong/a/@href
```

This is very specific to the Kentucky table: `following-sibling::table[1]` means the first `table` node after, and at the same level of, `a[@id='ky']`.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into it a little more and my code works in some Google Spreadsheet and doesn't work in other.  If I copy the same code in to an old sheet it works fine.  It appears to be a problem with the new version of Google sheets.